# validate global variable in Jenkins Templating Engine configuration

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-template-engine

Is there a way to validate variables defined in `global` scope just like how we validate variables for `libraries` using `library_config.groovy` file?
I have this variable defined in `global` scope because this is used across several libraries.

```
@merge keywords {
  @merge globals {
    @override someVar = "someVal"
  }
}
```

I would like to let the client change the value by setting them in their `pipeline_config.groovy` file.

Is there a file called `global_config.groovy` or something where I can define `optional{}` and `required{}` or may be even use Regex for `global` scope as well?

@steventerrana